# SQL select data based on a one to many relation

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I struggle a little with the following database entity relations:

[image]

I would like to create a query where I get all events for a user that is either the owner (item-user_id)
or a participant (participant-user_id)

I got back to native queries, cause they are more easy to try out.
But the one to many relation between the registration and the participant won't work for me.

Tried `joins`, `sub-queries` in the `where` clause and `unions` .. but nothing worked so far.
Here are some examples:

First the one with the union -> but it returns not the correct result

```
select e.id, e.has_location, e.has_registration, e.parent_id, e.published, e._end, e.start
from event e
         inner join item i on e.id = i.id
where i.user_id = 2 and start >= '2020-08-01T00:00:00'
union
select e.id, e.has_location, e.has_registration, e.parent_id, e.published, e._end, e.start
from event e
         inner join registration_participants r on r.registration_id = e.id
         inner join participant p on r.participants_id = p.id
where p.user_id = 2
  and e.has_registration
  and p.status != 'CANCELED'
  and start >= '2020-08-01T00:00:00'
order by start;
```

than the one with some sub query -> but result is also wrong

```
select e.id, e.has_location, e.has_registration, e.parent_id,
e.published, e.start, e._end from event e
         inner join item i on e.id = i.id where i.user_id = 2    or (select p.user_id
       from participant p
                inner join registration_participants r on e.id = r.registration_id
       where r.participants_id = p.id
         and p.status != 'CANCELED'
      ) = 2 order by e.start
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your data model and question are hard enough to follow.  The subsequent queries have additional conditions and rather odd join conditions.

Comment: You have `registration_participants` table in example query, but on the diagram. Please provide the complete picture to get better help

Comment: i added a more specific picture also with the correct table names. also to mention, even if it is very irregular as @GordonLinoff pointed out, i bring the stuff together by konvetion, what means that the id for registration, event and item is always (given by item id generated value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses `exists`:

```
select e.*
from event e
where exists (select 1 from item i where i.id = e.id and i.user_id = 2) or
      exists (select 1 from registration r where r.registration_id = e.id and r.participant = 2);
```

I am not sure what other conditions (such as on date and status are).  They are not described in the question or the data model.

That said, it seems *highly* irregular that the `join` condition between `item` and `event` would be on a column called `id`.  I would expect it to be using either `event_id` or `item_id`.  If you are having a problem, I suspect it involves the join conditions.

Comment: Thx for the fast reply .. i know its pretty irregular to use the same id, tried to make it more easy to access data by moving controll away from JPA/Hibernate ..

Comment: i was able to use that answer together with some slight modification on the jpa stuff to get rid of the ```registration_participants``` my moving from ```@ElementCollection``` to ```@OneToMany``` with ```@JoinColumn```